# How to test applications that use long polling with Protractor

Tags: angularjs, protractor, long-polling

I am building an Angular app that uses long polling to receive fast updates whenever something changes on the server. I use $resource like this to fetch the actual data:

```
appServices.factory('Data', ['$resource', 
  function(){
    return $resource('', {}, {
        query: {"url": …, isArray: false}
  });
}]);
```

Then I have a service that takes care of the long polling: Wait that the data are loaded; store them somewhere; after one second, start the next long-polling cycle:

```
app.factory(„DataLoader“, [„Data“, "$timeout", function(Data, $timeout) {
    return {
            loadData: function() {
                var parent = this;
                var data = Data.query({},
                        function(result) {
                          /* do something to the data,
                           * then start waiting for an update from the server again
                           */
                           $timeout(function() {
                                parent.loadData();
                           }, 1000);
                        }
                );
            }
     };
});
```

It works like a charm so far.

However, I am now trying to write Protractor tests for this. The problem is: The server times out the long polling requests after 30 seconds only if there are no changes to the data. As I am waiting for new data inside $timeout, Protractor times out before any results arrive.

I have googled the last hour, but there doesn't seem to be a solution except for using $interval instead of $timeout. This works in a good old polling setup (poll every 3 seconds, get empty results from the server if there's nothing new). However, to avoid exactly that, I implemented long polling. $timeout is just the much more sensible option for me.

Can you give me any tips how to get Protractor running successfully in this environment?

Comment: If you don't want to use `$interval`, I _think_ your only other option would be to disable Protractors synchronization with Angular.  `browser.ignoreSynchronization = true`;  Not sure if there's another option

Comment: Thanks for the hint, @Gunderson! I ended up doing just that and then manually wait for DOM elements to show up using expected conditions.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest taking a look at [Protractor's documentation on timeouts](http://www.protractortest.org/#/timeouts). You will probably need to increase your `allScriptsTimeout` in your configuration file since the default wait for page synchronization is 11 seconds.

Comment: Thought about that too, only issue is that then the test execution takes incredibly much time.

Comment: @fjc did you get any solution for this issue?

Comment: I did end up turning on browser.ignoreSynchronization and increasing the timeout. Not a very satisfying solution. It all became much more easily testable with Angular + RXJS. So if it's an option, I'd recommend just migrating to Angular.

Comment: Increasing  allScriptsTimeout  will not have any affect on the tests, because the page polls continuously and protractor waits for indefinite amount of time, so even though you increase the allScriptsTimeout that will just delay the test for some more time and fails.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$interval` angular api and `$fetch` for polling data continuously in your app

If you dont want to use `$interval` instead of `$timeout`; which is not a good practice, 
then you have to turn off the browser synchronization with angular `browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false)` and use either `browser.sleep()` or `browser.wait()` to achieve synchronization between the elements that you interact with on the page.